# Не заносяться данные в БД

Tags: php, mysql

Делаю регистрацию на сайте с помощу php, ошибок не выдает никаких, но в БД данные не заносятся.
Пробовал разные варианты кода. Версия `php` (на хостинге) - `PHP Version 5.5.26`

Код php:

```
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dblogin = "u829570674_eu";
$dbpassword = "lfeu29";
$dbName = "u829570674_lf";

// Creat connection
    $connect = new mysqli($dbhost, $dblogin, $dbpassword, $dbName);
// Check connection
    if($connect->connect_error){
        die("Connect error: " . $connect->connect_error);
    }
    $connect->select_db('users');

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $username = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']);
        $surname = htmlspecialchars($_POST['surname']);
        $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['mail']);
        $password = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']);
        if(strlen($password) > 5){
            $password = md5($password);
            $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, surname, email, password) VALUES ($username','$surname','$email','$password')";
            //die("INSERT INTO users ('username','surname','email','password') VALUES (".$username.",".$surname.",".$email.",".$password.")");
            echo 'Дякую за реєстрацію Yes';
        }else{
            die ('Некорректно заповненно!  No');
        }
    }
```

Html:

```
   <form method="post" action="" id="form-register">
           <h2 class="title">Реєстрація</h2>
      <div class="id_info">
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Iм'я" class="name" required>
        <input type="text" name="surname" placeholder="Прізвище" class="surname" required><br>
        <input type="mail" name="mail" placeholder="Ел.почта" class="email" required>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Пароль" class="password" required><br>
      </div>
         <button type="submit" name="submit" id="btn-register">Зареєструватись</button> 
  </form>
```

Comment: Собственно, а где вы их заносите в БД? Я вот вижу только `sql` запрос, но никак не исполнение. Что-то типа `$connect->query($sql);` и т.д.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

В вашем коде между

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, surname, email, password) VALUES ($username','$surname','$email','$password')";
        //die("INSERT INTO users ('username','surname','email','password') VALUES (".$username.",".$surname.",".$email.",".$password.")");
```

и

```
    echo 'Дякую за реєстрацію Yes';
```

нет ни каких видимых попыток выполнить запрос который у вас в переменной $sql

Comment: А чего не хватает? Что нужно дописать?  Делал по примеру с видео, у того человека все работает

Comment: так надо на пример взглянуть, записи в базу не хватает, тут не видно что не хватает ибо неизвестный пример...

Comment: если ответ был правильным, отметьте его галочкой.

Comment: Нет, проблема была с $username - перед $username не поставил кавычку и email не был  = с mail в базе. изза этого была проблема

Comment: проблема изначально была в том что у вас отсутствовал код if ($connect->query($sql) === TRUE) { а про кавычки это вы уже в копии обсуждали другую проблему.